# jQuery - DOM shorthand to $(myobj).children(...).children(...).children(...)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I want to navigate within a particular table, stored in a variable.

I want to find all inputs in the tr in the thead of the table.

If I had the id of the table I cold do this -

```
$('#mytable thead tr input')
```

But say I have stored the table in a variable, and I don't know the table's id anymore - `var mytableVar=$('#mytable')`.

Now if I want to still navigate to that input, I could do this -

```
$(mytableVar).children('thead').children('tr').children('input')
```

Is there a shorter way to do this, instead of having to iterating on `.children(...)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

```
mytableVar.find('> thead > tr > input')
```

Comment: Look at the start of the question, not just the title : the > aren't necessary

Comment: then it will select the thead from any level instead of child thead of the `mytableVar`

Comment: 1. What do the >'s mean?

2. For this question it doesn't matter, but what if I wanted to ensure that the 'thead' is not deep within the table, and is a child of the $(mytableVar)? Does that happen with this lookup?

Comment: Yes, of course, which is OK in 99% or real cases and was exactly what he was doing...

Comment: I guess you already answered my question while I was typing it. Thanks!

Comment: just one thing, you don't need to wrap `mytableVar` in jQuery object following OP's code

Answer (score 3):

To use a variable for your table in `$('#mytable thead tr input')`, you can do this :

```
mytableVar.find('thead tr input')
```

or

```
$('thead tr input', mytableVar)
```

Note that the `tr` is very probably useless there, so simply use

```
$('thead input', mytableVar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course:

```
$(mytableVar).find('thead > tr > input')
```

or:

```
$(mytableVar).find('input')
```